# Getting all documents from one collection in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm starting with javascript and react-native and I'm trying to figure out this problem for hours now. Can someone explain me how to get all the documents from firestore collection ?

I have been trying this:

```
async getMarkers() {
  const events = await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        console.log('LOG 1', doc.data());
        return doc.data();
      });
    });
  console.log('LOG 2', events);
  return events;
}
```

Log 1 prints all the objects(one by one) but log 2 is undefined, why ?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

The example in the other answer is unnecessarily complex.  This would be more straightforward, if all you want to do is return the raw data objects for each document in a query or collection:

```
async getMarker() {
    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()
    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
}
```

Comment: this worked for me `const snapshot = await firestore.collection('events').get()`

Comment: @etoxin That would work only if your imports/requires were different than what the OP was doing.

Comment: Would this count towards one read for the quota, or would each document in the collection count as a read operation?

Comment: @Mentor The query will incur a read for every matched document, regardless of what you do with the snapshots in your code.

Comment: `const events = await firestore.collection('events').get().then(snapshot => snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))`

Comment: would this do one trip to db or one per each document?

Comment: @bermick one query is one round trip.  The entire results of the query come back in the snapshot.

Comment: snapshot.docs no longer functions or is deprecated @DougStevenson

Comment: @MisterSirCode No, [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) is still a property on QuerySnapshot.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I was confusing Firebase Real-time Database and Firestore... turns out I was accidentally on the database documentation instead of firestore, so it's all good

Comment: how does this answer work with the new syntax?

Comment: What's the limit for this. Let's say 10 million documents, will it work?

Answer (score 36):

if you want include Id

```
async getMarkers() {
  const events = await firebase.firestore().collection('events')
  events.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const tempDoc = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }
      })
      console.log(tempDoc)
    })
}
```

Same way with array

```
async getMarkers() {
  const events = await firebase.firestore().collection('events')
  events.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const tempDoc = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         tempDoc.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
      })
      console.log(tempDoc)
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 13):

I made it work this way:

```
async getMarkers() {
  const markers = [];
  await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      markers.push(doc.data());
    });
  });
  return markers;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

if you need to include the key of the document in the response, another alternative is:

```
async getMarker() {
    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()
    const documents = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
       const document = { [doc.id]: doc.data() };
       documents.push(document);
    }
    return documents;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) state:

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

However I am using the following (excuse the TypeScript):

```
import { collection, Firestore, getDocs, Query, QueryDocumentSnapshot, QuerySnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore'

const q: Query<any> = collection(db, 'videos')
const querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot<IVideoProcessed> = await getDocs(q)
const docs: QueryDocumentSnapshot<IVideoProcessed>[] = querySnapshot.docs
const videos: IVideoProcessed[] = docs.map((doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot<IVideoProcessed>) => doc.data())
```

where db has the type `Firestore`

Answer (score 6):

You could get the whole collection as an object, rather than array like this:

```
async function getMarker() {
    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()
    const collection = {};
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        collection[doc.id] = doc.data();
    });
    return collection;
}
```

That would give you a better representation of what's in firestore. Nothing wrong with an array, just another option.

Answer (score 3):

Two years late but I just began reading the Firestore documentation recently cover to cover for fun and found `withConverter` which I saw wasn't posted in any of the above answers.  Thus:

If you want to include ids *and* also use `withConverter` (Firestore's version of ORMs, like ActiveRecord for Ruby on Rails, Entity Framework for .NET, etc), then this might be useful for you:

Somewhere in your project, you probably have your `Event` model properly defined.  For example, something like:

Your model (in `TypeScript`):
`./models/Event.js`

```js
export class Event {
  constructor (
    public id: string,
    public title: string,
    public datetime: Date
  )
}

export const eventConverter = {
  toFirestore: function (event: Event) {
    return {
      // id: event.id,  // Note! Not in ".data()" of the model!
      title: event.title,
      datetime: event.datetime
    }
  },
  fromFirestore: function (snapshot: any, options: any) {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)
    const id = snapshot.id
    return new Event(id, data.title, data.datetime)
  }
}
```

And then your client-side `TypeScript` code:

```js
import { eventConverter } from './models/Event.js'

...

async function loadEvents () {
  const qs = await firebase.firestore().collection('events')
    .orderBy('datetime').limit(3)  // Remember to limit return sizes!
    .withConverter(eventConverter).get()

  const events = qs.docs.map((doc: any) => doc.data())

  ...
}
```

Two interesting quirks of Firestore to notice (or at least, I thought were interesting):

1. Your `event.id` is actually stored "one-level-up" in `snapshot.id` and ***not*** `snapshot.data()`.
2. If you're using TypeScript, the TS linter (or whatever it's called) sadly isn't smart enough to understand:

`const events = qs.docs.map((doc: Event) => doc.data())`

even though right above it you explicitly stated:
`.withConverter(eventConverter)`

Which is why it needs to be `doc: any`.

(***But!***  You will *actually* get **`Array<Event>`** back! (Not **`Array<Map>`** back.) That's the entire point of `withConverter`... That way if you have any object methods (not shown here in this example), you can immediately use them.)

It makes sense to me but I guess I've gotten so greedy/spoiled that I just kinda expect my VS Code, ESLint, and the TS Watcher to literally do *everything* for me.  Oh well.

---

Formal docs (about `withConverter` and more) here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to hide all code complexity in my services... so, I generally use something like this:

**In my events.service.ts**

```
    async getEvents() {
        const snapchot = await this.db.collection('events').ref.get();
        return new Promise <Event[]> (resolve => {
            const v = snapchot.docs.map(x => {
                const obj = x.data();
                obj.id = x.id;
                return obj as Event;
            });
            resolve(v);
        });
    }
```

**In my sth.page.ts**

```
   myList: Event[];

   construct(private service: EventsService){}

   async ngOnInit() {
      this.myList = await this.service.getEvents();
   }
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

In version 9 sdk of firebase you can get all the documents from a collection using following query:

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

See [Get multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version of the top answer, but going into an object with the document ids:

```
async getMarker() {
    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()
    return snapshot.docs.reduce(function (acc, doc, i) {
              acc[doc.id] = doc.data();
              return acc;
            }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General example to get products from Cloud Firestore:

```dart
  Future<void> getAllProducts() async {
    CollectionReference productsRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');
    final snapshot = await productsRef.get();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> map =
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code pulls the data from Firebase collection named messages

```
Future<void> getMessages() async {
    try {
      await for (var snapshot
          in _fireStore.collection("messages").snapshots()) {
        for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
          print("Messages :: ${doc.data()}");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Where the `_firstore` is created in the state class of your stateful widget

```
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

It prints output at console

```
I/flutter (25195): Messages :: {sender: user1@gmail.com, text: Hello}
I/flutter (25195): Messages :: {sender: autobot, text: this is from firestore edited}
```

Dependencies in pubspec.yaml:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.25.4
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.4
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.5
```

Dart version

```
dart --version   
Dart SDK version: 3.2.6 (stable)
```

Flutter Version

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable •
```

Answer (score -1):

All answers are true, but when you have heavy data you will face memory and bandwidth problems, so you have to write a [cursor] function to read data part by part.

also, you may face to Bandwidth Exhausted error, please have a look at this solution I have implemented on a gist
https://gist.github.com/navidshad/973e9c594a63838d1ebb8f2c2495cf87

Otherwise, you can use this cursor I written to read a collection doc by doc:

```js
async function runCursor({
    collection,
    orderBy,
    limit = 1000,
    onDoc,
    onDone,
}) {
    let lastDoc;
    let allowGoAhead = true;

    const getDocs = () => {
        let query = admin.firestore().collection(collection).orderBy(orderBy).limit(limit)
        // Start from last part
        if (lastDoc) query = query.startAfter(lastDoc)

        return query.get().then(sp => {
            if (sp.docs.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < sp.docs.length; i++) {
                    const doc = sp.docs[i];
                    if (onDoc) onDoc(doc);
                }
                // define end of this part
                lastDoc = sp.docs[sp.docs.length - 1]
                // continue the cursor
                allowGoAhead = true
            } else {
                // stop cursor if there is not more docs
                allowGoAhead = false;
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    // Read part by part
    while (allowGoAhead) {
        await getDocs();
    }

    onDone();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I understand your query, This is because how Javascript handles promises and variables. So basically events variable is hoisted with the value undefined and printed on the LOG 2 console log, while the Event Loop responsible for the promise call resulted in an array of objects as the value of the events variable and then the console log (LOG 1) was printed with the resolved promise response