# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined? (React-firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is wrong in what i am doing, i am getting collection snapshot, looping through it and push it to the state then use that state to render some list items
but i get that error:
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

**Code:**

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
db.collection('books').get()
   .then(snapshot => snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      setBooks([...books, doc.data()])
}))

return (
  books.map(return some jsx)
)
```

Comment: have you tried this in return `books && books.map(return some jsx)` ?

Comment: yes i tried it but never worked! @shubhamjha

Comment: may be you could try with empty value like `setBooks([])` in forEach  and log the `doc` and `doc.data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing too many `setState`. Why not simply do it once?

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
db.collection('books')
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => snapshot.map(s => s.data())
  .then(data => setBooks(data))
}))

return (
  books.map(b => <div>{book stuff here}</div>)
)
```

Comment: unfortunately, i get that error
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): snapshot.map is not a function`
The same error that pushed me to use forEach

Comment: @CodeEagle, that only means your `db` query is not returning an array. Log the `snapshot` variable and see what's in there.

Comment: @CodeEagle, this is probably what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101894/1693859

Comment: yes, thank you, it is `snapshot.docs` not just snapshot, but i still have the same problem using your solution still the same error, it should work but for some reason it doesn't

Comment: Debug it. Put a `debugger` statement inside the `then(snapshot => { debugger })` and look at the devtool to see what's inside of it.

Comment: it worked finally, thank you you saved me too much rerendering!