# Get all documents in collection using Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read several documentation but I don't understand why I should use an extra layer(foreach) in my code when I read all of the data inside a collection using Firebase (Cloud Firestore).

Here is the original documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Here is my code:

```
  async loadUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    const users = new Array<User>();
    const snapshot = await this.firestore.collection('users').get();
    snapshot.forEach((collection) => {
      collection.docs.forEach(doc => {
        users.push(doc.data() as User);
      });
    });
    return users;
  }
```

As I understand it should work like this:

```
async loadUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    const users = new Array<User>();
    const snapshot = await this.firestore.collection('users').get();
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      users.push(doc.data() as User);
    });
    return users;
  }
```

Error message:
"Property 'data' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'."

Comment: I'm confused.  Your first code sample doesn't look at all correct.  If all you're trying to do is iterate documents in a collection, you don't need a second forEach loop.  The second code sample looks correct.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, you are right, the first code sample doesn't look good, but it's work somehow and the second does not. This is what I want to understand... why?

Comment: dupe of?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100103/getting-all-documents-from-one-collection-in-firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.collection().get()` does NOT return an array; it returns a QuerySnapshot, which has a *property* `.docs`, which is an array of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, each of which has a *property* `.data`, which is the data read from the document.

Documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference

Answer (score 2):

In new modular firebase firestore(version 9.+) it should be like this:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, query, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
async readAll() {
  const firestore = getFirestore()
  const collectionRef = collection(firestore, '/users')
  let q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('createTimestamp', 'desc'))
    
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
  const items = []
  querySnapshot.forEach(document => {
     items.push(document.data())
  })
  return items
}
```

I could not find any parameter on `querySnapshot` directly that is something like `.docs` was and included whole array before. So it is kinda like onSnapshot is and was.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @LeadDreamer answer, I could manage to simplify the code

```
  async loadUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    const users = new Array<User>();
    await this.firestore.collection('users').get().subscribe(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        users.push(doc.data() as User);
      });
    });
    return users;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no other way but to iterate.

```
  const q = query(collection(db, "item"));
  getDocs(q).then( response => {
    const result = response.docs.map(doc=>({ 
      id: doc.id, 
      ...doc.data(),
    }))
    console.log(result);
  }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```