# How to read a lot of documents (1M+) from a collection in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The code below fails with error `9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old.`

```
const ref = db.collection('Collection');
const snapshot = await ref.get();
snapshot.forEach((doc,index) => {
   ...use data
})
```

[Getting all documents from one collection in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100103/getting-all-documents-from-one-collection-in-firestore)

---

EDIT:

```
getData();


async function getData(doc) {

  let snapshot = await global.db.collection('Collection').orderBy().startAfter(doc).limit(5000).get();

  const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
  
  snapshot.forEach((doc,index) => {
      //...use data
  })


  if (snapshot.docs.length < 5000) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    getData(last)
  }
}
```

EDIT 2 (works, a bit slow, reads sequentially, 5000 docs at a time):

```
let snapshot = null;
let totalIndex = 0;

await getData();

async function getData(doc) {

  if (!doc) {
    const first = await global.db.collection("collection").doc("docID");
    snapshot = await global.db.collection('collection').orderBy(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()).startAt(first).limit(5000).get();
  }
  else {
    snapshot = await global.db.collection('Prompts').orderBy(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()).startAfter(doc).limit(5000).get();
  }

  const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
  
  snapshot.forEach((doc,index) => {
     console.log(totalIndex++);
     //...use data
  })


  if (snapshot.docs.length < 5000) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    getData(last)
  }
}
```

Comment: Trying to read a million documents in one go sounds like a recipe for problems. Did you consider [reading a limited number of those document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) initially, process than and then [using pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to read further chunks of the data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is what I am exploring atm (question edited) Currently getting "Error: Value for argument "fieldPath" is not a valid field path. The path cannot be omitted." I thought that .startAfter might accept no parameter and just start at the first item, but checking docs atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're initially calling `getData()` without any arguments, that leads to `doc` being `undefined` in that function body. And calling `startAfter(undefined)` is not valid.

What you'll want to do is optionally adding that `startAfter` with something like:

```
async function getData(doc) {
  let query = global.db.collection('Collection').orderBy();
  if (doc) {
    query = query.startAfter(doc);
  }
  let snapshot = await query.limit(5000).get();
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, just checked the docs and think I fixed this and other issues. Could you please check EDIT 2 ?

Comment: EDIT 2 seems to be working although it is quite slow :(

Comment: Please don't post a question that is a moving target. In just 30 minutes this went from the really broad title for which I commented, to a code snippet with a concrete problem that I answered, to another concrete code problem. That is neither sustainable for those of us who are trying to help, nor useful in building a knowledge base that is useful for future visitors.