# Strange formatting of cloud firestore documents in react.js

Tags: reactjs, json, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app with React.js and Cloud Firestore. When I read data,, it is formatted strangely. I am using `getFirestore(app)` to export the database through the entire project. For example if I have a document looking like that:

```
{
name: "John"
age: 29
friends: ["Mike", "Sarah"]
}
```

, when I'll read it within the app, I'll get something like:

```
{
mapValue:{
fields:{
name:{stringValue: "John"}
age: {numberValue: 29}
friends: {arrayValue:{values:
{stringValue: "Mike"},
{stringValue: "Sarah"}
}}
}
```

so if I want to access "Mike", I'll need `user.mapValue.fields.friends.arrayValue.values[0].stringValue` instead of `user.friends[0]`
It's making the development really complicated as I'm dealing with a lot of data and nested arrays. Is there a way to directly retrieve data in the simple form ? ask me if you need more info. Here's the code:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({}) 
    useEffect(()=>{
          async function getUser() {
            const q = query(collection(db, "teachers"), where("uid", "==", auth.currentUser.uid));
           const docs = await getDocs(q);
           setUserData(docs.docs[0]._document.data.value.mapValue.fields)
          }
          getUser()
      
        }, [])
console.log(userData)
```

Comment: You should edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  There should be enough information that anyone can use the reproduce the problem as you see it.  I suggest reading this to learn more about how to build a complete minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The `_document` in `docs.docs[0]._document.data.value.mapValue.fields` means that you're accessing private internals of the SDK Can't you use `docs.doc]0].data()`?

Comment: When I try with `docs.docs[0].data`, it   returns                                                                `data() {
    let t = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : {};
    return super.data(t);
  }`

Comment: Maybe try any of these - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100103/getting-all-documents-from-one-collection-in-firestore